# Drag shadow is square for a round floating action button

Tags: android, floating-action-button

I am on Android Lollipop (minSdk=21), and want to implement moving a Floating Action Button around with a dragging gesture. The button is a custom subclass of ImageButton, the code is described here so I won't repeat it: [Define default values for layout_width and layout_height properties for a subclass in a style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27890953/define-default-values-for-layout-width-and-layout-height-properties-for-a-subcla)

For dragging, I use the way described here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/drag-drop.html. Here is what my code looks like:

```
    favoriteButton.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            v.startDrag(null, new View.DragShadowBuilder(v), null, 0);

            return true;
        }
    });

    findViewById(R.id.test_main_layout).setOnDragListener(new View.OnDragListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
                    favoriteButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    break;

                case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
                    favoriteButton.setX(event.getX() - favoriteButton.getWidth() / 2);
                    favoriteButton.setY(event.getY() - favoriteButton.getHeight() / 2);
                    favoriteButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    break;
            }

            return true;
        }
    });
```

Generally, it works, but the problem is the 'drag shadow': it is square. For this reason or the other, it doesn't respect the oval outline of the FAB.

How can I make it behave correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@FD_ thank you for your answer. In the meantime, while trying to ask something in a comment, I noticed that my background drawable used for the FAB is not an oval shape but rather a simple color:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:color="?android:attr/colorControlHighlight">

    <item android:drawable="?android:attr/colorAccent"/>

</ripple>
```

After changing it to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:color="?android:attr/colorControlHighlight">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/oval_accent_drawable"/>

</ripple>
```

with another oval drawable with the wanted color:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:shape="oval">

    <solid android:color="?android:attr/colorAccent"/>

    <size
        android:width="@dimen/fab_size"
        android:height="@dimen/fab_size"/>

</shape>
```

the drag shadow now works perfectly.

Thank you for being my [rubber duck](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging%20%22rubber%20duck%22.).

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest implementing your own subclass of `DragShadowBuilder`:
Only override `onDrawShadow()` and draw a circle of the size the FAB has. Then simply use that class in `startDrag()`.

If your FAB is an `ImageButton`, you might already have an image you could use for the shadow, so that you don't even have to draw a circle. You could simply draw the same image to the `Canvas` in `onDrawShadow()`. Here is an example of how a shadow can be built from an image: https://gist.github.com/MarcinGil/5337109.